# Looking for a cleaner code to map a list of dict result

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have an output like this:

```
[{'label': 'LABEL_0', 'score': 0.9994072914123535}]
```

using this code to output the final sentiment analyse:

```
def _sentiment(t):
    res = classifier(t)
    if res[0]['label']=='LABEL_0':
        return "positive" 
    if res[0]['label']=='LABEL_1':
        return "neutral"
    else: 
        return "negative"
```

The code above works fine but I'd like to know if there's a better way to write the `_sentiment` function.  By better way I mean, better performance and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The below code can answer your question:

```
sentiments = {'LABEL_0': 'positive', 'LABEL_1': 'neutral'}

def _sentiment(t):
    res = classifier(t)
    key = res[0]['label']
    sentiment = sentiments.get(key, 'negative')
    return sentiment
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Python 3.10 you can use [match statements](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#pep-634-structural-pattern-matching):

```
def _sentiment(t):
    res = classifier(t)
    match res[0]['label']:
        case  'LABEL_0':
            return "positive" 
        case 'LABEL_1':
            return "neutral"
        case _:
            return "negative"
```